# Having a subfield searched under '_all' in elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have a field that has a subdivision, like:

```
             //name
            .startObject(IndexConstants.FIRST_NAME)
            .field("type").value("string")
            .startObject("fields")
            .startObject("folded")
            .field("type").value("string")
            .field("analyzer").value("folding")
            .endObject()
            .endObject()
```

The _all field only searches on firstname, not firstname.folded. If I specifically query on .folded it works, however it is a catch all query so I would not like to have to specify folded.
I have tried the "include_in_all" true for it but no change.

Thanks

Comment: Which `query` are you using for searching? I mean `term` or `query_string` or `match` or anything else.

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in the [official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/include-in-all.html), it makes no sense to use `include_in_all` in multi-fields:

> The original field value is added to the `_all` field, not the terms produced by a field’s analyzer. For this reason, it makes no sense to set `include_in_all` to `true` on multi-fields, as each multi-field has exactly the same value as its parent.

Using `copy_to` could be an option with versions <2.x. However, using `copy_to` with multi-fields [will be ignored as of 2.0](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking_20_mapping_changes.html#_copy_to_and_multi_fields) and even throw an exception as of 2.0.1 and 2.1.

You're better off matching directly on `firstname.folded`, if it is really important for you to query that sub-field, simply use its `folding` analyzer on the main `firstname` field and get rid of the sub-field.

Comment: copy_to would copy the original value, not the folded value, unfortunately, I would require the query to be on _all.

Comment: I might just have to add a client side folded version when inserting the index